# nodejs writing protopayload in google-cloud/logging

Tags: node.js, logging, google-cloud-logging

How do we pass a protopayload union label using google-cloud/logging package in NodeJS?

So far i am able to write textPayload and jsonPayload in the logs.

Tried creating a protocol buffer using google-protobuf and also protobufjs and even tried protocol-buffer packages, but the payload is not seen in the logs when i do log.entry and log.write.

This is the code for writing logs

//writelogs.js

```
function writeLogEntryAdvanced (logName, options, callback) {
  var logging = Logging();
  var log = logging.log(logName);
var protobuf = require('protocol-buffers');
var fs = require('file-system');
// pass a proto file as a buffer/string or pass a parsed protobuf-schema object
var messages = protobuf(fs.readFileSync('test.proto'));
var buf = messages.Test.encode({
  num: 42,
  payload: 'hello world'
});
console.log(buf);
var entry = log.entry({ resource: options.resource }, buf);
  // See https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/logging/latest/logging/log?method=write
  log.write(entry, function (err, apiResponse) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    console.log('Wrote entry to log: %s', logName);
    return callback(null, apiResponse);
});
}
```

//test.proto

```
message Test {
  required float num  = 1;
  required string payload = 2;
}
```

the writing code is copied from nodejs-doc-samples from github with few changes of my own for protopayload.
The sample logs writing was only for jsonPayload and textPayload.

Comment: When using the [Stackdriver Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer), ensure you are viewing the correct 'logName' and 'resource.type' that you are writing the log to. Also be sure that your 'test.proto' follows the [Google Protocol Buffer language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#simple). If you are seeing the log, but not the payload, the issue is most likely due to your encoder. You can try using [google-protobuf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-protobuf) as an alternative to 'protocol-buffers'.

Comment: @jordan Yes i can see the logs but not the payload. I will try google-protobuf as an alternative.
Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to your issue? If so it is recommended to post it as the answer here to better help the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of an arbitrary protocol buffer for the protoPayload field in the Logging API is not allowed. Only a few Google Cloud Platform services with well-known descriptors are allowed to be used in this field.

For arbitrary structured logging, you should use the jsonPayload field.

More info about these fields are documented in: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry.

Answer (score 2):

*For completeness I am posting my last comment as an answer.*

When using the [Stackdriver Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer), ensure that you are viewing the correct 'logName' and 'resource.type' that you are writing the log to.

Also be sure that your 'test.proto' follows the [Google Protocol Buffer language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#simple). If you are seeing the log, but not the payload, the issue is most likely due to your encoder. You can try using [google-protobuf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-protobuf) as an alternative to 'protocol-buffers'.